# Android C2DM Invalidregistration

Tags: c#, asp.net, android, push-notification, android-c2dm

I have created an android app, that registering to google c2dm service. And It's getting a registration_id token from c2dm services successfully.

I already signed Android Cloud to Device Messaging form and I received confirmation email from c2dm service.

Everything seems ok in client side, it's getting registration_id in simulator environment. So, it's ok.

But, On server side, It's authenticating google service, it's receiving Auth code then it's invoking to c2dm send url with below code.

```
  public void SendMessage(string registrationId, string data)
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate(
                                            object sender,
                                            X509Certificate certificate,
                                            X509Chain chain,
                                            SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            return true;
        };

        string collapseKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");          

        string url = "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=DQAAAKYAAACE_0NqG8Sj5lBf4YSPXs_ltQbTzPsAL5u1Q1KGF...");

        string px = "registration_id=" + registrationId + "&collapse_key=" + collapseKey + "&data.payload=" + data;
        string encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(px);

        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] buffer = encoding.GetBytes(encoded);

        Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        newStream.Close();




         HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
         if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
         {
             Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
             StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resStream);
             Console.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
             sr.Close();
             resStream.Close();
         }
         Console.WriteLine();
         Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

It's still receiving `Error=InvalidRegistration` response from c2dm service.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you upload your project source ?

Comment: Can you please share your source code of both server & client side? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, It solved.
I removed `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(px);` and everything worked as I expected.

Comment: Good to see you resolved it. Just fyi: You should only encode querystring values, not the querystring itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a long time until I set the ContentType to-

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

You need to set it to that for both

- the authentication stage and,
- the send message.

I then got the `NotRegistered` error but that is due to not using the same account on the phone as the sender for the server authentication.

Hope that helps others.