# Push Notification for android in wcf data service

Tags: android, c#-4.0, windows-services, wcf-data-services

is there any sample code or project available for implementing android push notification service in c#.
i want to develope a data service to send notification to android phones is there any API or Helper class available for implementing android push notification in c#.

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost sure that WCF and especially WCF data services are not technologies designed for PUSH notifications - WCF services are designed for PULL scenarios (= pooling). The only exception are duplex WCF services which introduce large complexity and are not interoperable. WCF Data Services are based on REST / OData and doesn't support PUSH.

Comment: is there any helper class available for #

Comment: I don't know about any.  Here are some related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514255/android-push-notification-using-net http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509029/android-c2dm-invalidregistration

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pushing data to the mobile, you may develop a scheduling service in the mobile client that gets data from the enterprise server in a predefined interval.

Comment: I agree with this, just poll from the client phone in intervals determined by constraints on the phone like total battery life and battery life remaining.